# How to put scheduled restart in CentOS7?

Tags: centos, centos7

How to create scheduled restart in Centos7, I want to restart my Centos7 server for every day at 4PM

Comment: Just use `at` or `crond` and run a script with the `reboot` command inside.

Comment: duplicate: https://serverfault.com/questions/155239/how-can-i-schedule-a-reboot-in-linux

Answer (score 6):

Please try the below command. it will restart the computer in the midle of the night.

**shutdown -r 0:00**

Same can be done adding the below line /etc/crontab

**0 0 * * * /sbin/shutdown -r now**

Comment: The shutdown command is a one-time reboot while the crontab would be every night though, right?

Answer (score 1):

open crontab config file

```
vim /etc/crontab
```

Put the following line in the crontab

```
0 16 * * * /usr/sbin/reboot
```

Or 
    crontab -e

put the above line

```
    0 16 * * * /usr/sbin/reboot
```

and restart crontab

```
systemctl restart crond.service
```

[contab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lZmcw.png)